# cross domain postmessage() via popup in ie8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

Is there a way to use postmessage() crossdomain via popup in ie8. I wish to run one function on the parent page after the user performs a action(login) in the popup. How do sites like facebook do it.

Comment: [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage) works cross-domain, that's the point.  If you make a popup, and keep a reference to its `window` object, you can send it messages.

Comment: but cross domain it doesn't work

Comment: `postMessage` might not work properly in IE8: http://caniuse.com/#search=postMessage

Comment: You can try using: http://easyxdm.net/wp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross-domain `PostMessage` in IE8 is [limited to frame/iframe relationships](http://caniuse.com/x-doc-messaging), it is not allowed to cross tabs or windows.

You can mimic its behaviour by using a switchboard server via websockets, with fallback to longpolling for older browsers via for example [Socket.io](http://socket.io/). You would then broadcast a message via the switchboard that the other tab or windows can subscribe to to know when login has succeeded/failed.

Comment: How would your suggestions work at all? If they're on different domains, I doubt there's one "switchboard server" that can broadcast using any of those methods... It makes more sense to **not** use a popup window, use a modal dialog instead with an iframe, so that the iframe can communicate

Comment: Why not? All available methods can be accessed from any domain if properly configured. All you'd need is a simple node.js server relaying the messages, and nobody cares what domain boundaries are crossed. I do agree using a popup for this only complicates matters needlessly if cross-domain **and** IE8 compatibility are required. For Facebook and the like it doesn't matter, they have the entire realtime infrastructure already.

Comment: I think I just needed an explanation :) I also might have misunderstood, so either way, that sounds pretty good +1